# java class that extend HashMap <String, Map <String, List<String> > overwrite method put dont work

Tags: java, dictionary, put

Hi i have a problem with this my class:

```
public class JarClassMethod extends HashMap<String,HashMap<String, List<String>>> {
    public JarClassMethod() {
        super();
    }

    public List<String> get(String jar,String classe) {
        return get(jar).get(classe);
    }

    public void put(String jar, String classe, List<String> metodi) {

        Map<String,List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put(classe, metodi);
        this.put(jar, (HashMap<String, List<String>>) map2);
    }

}
```

if call put in a for cycle i view at end only last value in my MAP object!

example:

```
{"jar1":{classe1:[s,adas,da,sd],
         classe2:[asda,fdd,ass],
        },
"jar2":{classe3:[s,adas,da,sd],
         classe4:[asda,fdd,ass],
        }
}
```

Thks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `put` method is replacing the inner map for the given `jar` key, so only the last `classe` for a given `jar` key will be retained. You should only put a new inner `HashMap` when the `jar` key doesn't already have one.

The method implementation should be:

```
public void put(String jar, String classe, List<String> metodi) {
    computeIfAbsent(jar, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(classe, metodi);
}
```

Also, to prevent `NullPointerException`, your `get` method should be:

```
public List<String> get(String jar, String classe) {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> classeMap = get(jar);
    return (classeMap == null ? null : classeMap.get(classe));
}
```

*Test*

```
JarClassMethod jcm = new JarClassMethod();
jcm.put("jar1", "classe1", Arrays.asList("s","adas","da","sd"));
jcm.put("jar1", "classe2", Arrays.asList("asda","fdd","ass"));
jcm.put("jar2", "classe3", Arrays.asList("s","adas","da","sd"));
jcm.put("jar2", "classe4", Arrays.asList("asda","fdd","ass"));
jcm.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

*Output*

```
jar2={classe4=[asda, fdd, ass], classe3=[s, adas, da, sd]}
jar1={classe2=[asda, fdd, ass], classe1=[s, adas, da, sd]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` overwrites the previous value if you put a new value for an existing key. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) which states:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced by the specified value.

Check your loop if you are always calling `put` with the same key. If yes, in the end, the `Map` will have just one value which is the last value put into it.

Make sure to create a new object referenced by `map2` as shown below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,HashMap<String, List<String>>> map=new HashMap<String,HashMap<String, List<String>>>();
        Map<String,List<String>> map2;      

        map2= new HashMap<>();      
        map2.put("classe1",List.of("s","adas","da","sd"));
        map2.put("classe2",List.of("asda","fdd","ass"));
        map.put("jar1", (HashMap<String, List<String>>) map2);      
        System.out.println(map);

        map2= new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("classe3",List.of("s","adas","da","sd"));
        map2.put("classe4",List.of("asda","fdd","ass"));
        map.put("jar2", (HashMap<String, List<String>>) map2);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{jar1={classe2=[asda, fdd, ass], classe1=[s, adas, da, sd]}}
{jar2={classe4=[asda, fdd, ass], classe3=[s, adas, da, sd]}, jar1={classe2=[asda, fdd, ass], classe1=[s, adas, da, sd]}}
```

Comment: i want a method put land my map is similar to:

{"jar":{classe1:[s,adas,da,sd],
         classe2:[asda,fdd,ass],
        }
}

Comment: I've added a note (`Make sure to create a new object referenced by map2`) to make it clear. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.